# Prevent density scaling in view

Tags: android, view, scaling

I have emulator with 480x800 resolution and density 1,5. So when I display any ad (admob, madvertise) with 320x50 resolution in the view it is scaled to 480 x 75.

This is how the layout looks like - the ad views are added with code into LinearLayout (id adsholder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.sbcgames.sbcengine.SBCGLView
        android:id="@+id/sbcglview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/adsholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Is there any way how to prevent scaling? I would like to keep the original pixel dimensions instead of idp. I tried to add this into manifest but it did not help:

```
 <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you displaying your ads in a `WebView`?

Comment: Put the size on the width and height instead of wrap_content, using px and not dp

Comment: No, for admob it is com.google.ads.AdView and for Madvertise it is de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseView - it is created by code and then added into my LinearLayout that is wraping the ads size.

Comment: @nininho - I tried to set fixed size but I only got the ad cut. The ad inside the view was not scaled.

Comment: You could try then having a fixed size on the ad layoutparams instead of the parent linearlayout

Comment: Why are you trying to change the scaling? - the whole point of the ad scaling is to maintain the the same touch target size across multiple devices/screen sizes.

Comment: @Morrison Chang - I just ported our bada game (Deadly Abyss 2) to Android and want to add ads to try to monetize it somehow. When running on tablet with density 1 there is lot of space for the ad. When running on mobile and density 1,5 it is obscuring important parts. If I managed to display it nonscaled I would just fit ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to enforce view (layout/image etc) size in real pixles (`px`). So:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adsholder"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

will always be 200x200 **pixels**, no matter of screen density. See [docs on the available units](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: I tired this but it only cut the ad in the view - inside of it there is part of density-scaled ad visible.

Comment: It works as it should because container units are NOT inherited by its children. Then check your ad SDK to see if there's any API to control that. Alternatively you could traverse all children of your `adsholder` layout and modify its LayoutParams, but my guess is that this would cause other problems.